# Index in Appendix

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, appendix

I have asked this question in another forum (Link: https://golatex.de/index-im-appendix-t22448.html), but have not received a satisfied answer. I wanted to set my "register of persons" in the appendix (in the MWE between "Anhang A: Allgemeine Ergänzungen" and "Anhang B: Abbildungen"). My problem is that the "register of persons" is not reckoned as an independent chapter, but as a part of "Anhang A". How it is possible to have these titles:

Anhang A: Allgemeine Ergänzungen
Anhang B: Personenregister
Anhang
   C:  Abbildungen

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mwe}
\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=Personen,title={Personenregister}]


\makeindex[name=Ort,title={Geographische Namen}]
\makeindex[name=sach,title={Sachregister}]
\makeindex
%HSS
%Sachen

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
dsfdsfsdfsdf\index[Personen]{sdfsdfsdf} sfsfgfdg

\appendix
\section{Allgemeine Ergänzungen}

\printindex[Personen]

\section{Abbildungen}

In diesem Anhang finden Sie alle Abbildungen zu \dots

\bigskip\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image}
  \captionof{figure}{Das erste Beispielbild}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \captionof{figure}{Ein anderes Bild. \blindtext}
\end{minipage}

\section{Tafeln}

In diesem Anhang finden Sie alle Tafeln und Tabellen zu \dots

\end{document}
```

One tip was to include: \indexsetup{level=\section} - but this did not solve the problem. I have seen, that, when I use "makeidx" (instead of "Imakeidx"; together with "\index" instead of "\index[Personen]") it works, but the advantage of \imakeidx is to great so that I would not switch to it.